# Altair: Values are still imputed, even though they should be deactivated

Tags: python, altair

I am having a problem with altair interactive plots. Below is small part of the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import random

n=300
dat = pd.DataFrame()
dat['X_axis'] = np.linspace(start=0.0, stop=1000, num = n)
mean = 4
std = 1
dat['Y_axis']=np.random.normal(loc=mean, scale=std, size = n)
dat['anom'] = np.random.choice([False, True ], size = (n,), p= [0.90, 0.10])

anomalies = alt.Chart(dat[dat['anom']==True]).mark_line(color='red').encode(x='X_axis', y=alt.Y('Y_axis', impute=alt.ImputeParams(value=None))).interactive()
normal = alt.Chart(dat[dat['anom']==False]).mark_line(color='blue').encode(x='X_axis',y=alt.Y('Y_axis', impute=alt.ImputeParams(value=None))).interactive()
display(alt.layer(anomalies, normal, title='Title_of_the_plot'))
```

The resulted graph is  [image]

As it can be seen from the graph, the blue line overlaps red, which means that instead of there being a gap (which is filled by the red line), the values are interpolated.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing the issue?

Comment: @jakevdp Just did

Comment: How did you define ``dat``?

Comment: @jakevdp . edited to reflect that

Comment: @jakevdp added another small edit to alt.layer( )

Comment: Your edit removes the link to the dataset, rendering the question less useful. I'd suggest reverting to the original question.

Comment: It has some sensitive content that I mistakenly uploaded the first time. I can easily update the `data.csv`. I would also like to edit the reply.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210447/discussion-between-eemamedo-and-jakevdp).

Answer (score 1):

The impute argument specifies what should be done with missing values. In the chart you shared, there are no missing values.

Why? Altair does not try to guess about what values you might consider "missing". There are a couple ways of indicating that results are missing:

- if you plot a grouped chart, and any of the groups is missing a value from one of the other groups, impute will fill in that value
- absent that, you can explicitly specify the `keyvals` argument to indicate which x-values you would like to consider "missing"

You have neither of these (each layer is a single group, and no keyvals are specified), so no values are imputed.

Probably the easiest way to address this is to use the color encoding in place of your manual filter+layer approach:

```
alt.Chart(dat).mark_line().encode(
    x='X_axis',
    y=alt.Y('Y_axis', impute=alt.ImputeParams(value=None)),
    color='anom'
).interactive()
```

[image]

Now values absent in one group and present in the other are considered "missing", and assigned a null value. There is still interpolation present between specified values, but this is because neither group defines values in this range. I suspect this is probably not what you want.

So you might try specifying `keyvals` to indicate which values you want to be considered missing. We can use `alt.ImputeSequence(val)` which effectively says you want all undefined integer values to be considered "missing":

```
alt.Chart(dat).mark_line().encode(
    x='X_axis',
    y=alt.Y('Y_axis', impute=alt.ImputeParams(value=None, keyvals=alt.ImputeSequence(dat.X_axis.max()))),
    color='anom'
).interactive()
```

[image]

The chart is empty, because your dataset contains no points at adjacent integer x values, so no line segments are drawn. This is probably not what you want.

So what do you want? Well, you haven't really defined that. You have to figure out which x-values you'd like to be considered "missing", and which you would not. Once you've decided on that, you can use the above methods to encode your intentions and create the chart you have in mind.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer. How would you address the gap (missing values) in the first plot? Is it possible to interpolate between two separate groups, and have a more continuous graph, instead of having gaps? I understand, that `keyvals` can be used but in the case of having one `for` loop where graphs are generated, `keyvals` will be changing constantly

Comment: If you want to interpolate values rather than nulls, you can set the impute parameters accordingly. See https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/impute.html

Comment: I am familiar with that link. My goal is to make the graph without any gaps; in other words, I am trying to have a continuous plot. What would be the best approach?

Comment: To make a continuous graph, you should set impute parameters according to how you want the values to be imputed.